# Regular Field Validator and JQuery Datepicker in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datepicker

I have a JQuery Datepicker in my asp form.

```
$(function () {
            $("#datepicker").datepicker();
        });

<tr>
   <td>Join Date
      </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="datepicker" class="box" />
             <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvdatepicker" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please Select a Join Date." ControlToValidate="datepicker" Enabled="false" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
</tr>
```

I am getting this error
"Unable to find control id 'datepicker' referenced by the 'ControlToValidate' property of 'rfvdatepicker'."

Please help me how to validate JQUERY datepicker using RegularFieldValidator
Also validate future dates using RegularExpressionValidator

Comment: You'll need to change your input to an asp.net control with `runat=server`. Just bear in mind that the id will be mangled by the runtime so select it via a class for the jQuery instead of an id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the error because the control does not have a "sever" id, which means it only exists on the client/browser side. You must assign "server" id by forcing the control to "run" at the server, so you must add `runat="server"` which was pointed-out in the comment by RobH.

Below is an example of how you can achieve this + regular-expression date-range validator:

**JavaScript:**

```
function pageLoad(sender, args) 
{
    $('#myDatePicker').datetimepicker({
        pickTime: false,
        pickDate: true,
        autoclose: true
    });
}
```

**ASPX:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <b>Join Date</b>
    <div class='input-group date' id='myDatePicker'>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="myJoinDatePicker" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-clock"></span></span>
    </div>
</div>

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvdatepicker" runat="server" 
    ErrorMessage="Please Select a Join Date." ControlToValidate="myJoinDatePicker"  
    Enabled="false" Display="Dynamic">
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regJoinDate" Display="Dynamic"
    ValidationExpression="^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|21)\d\d$"
    runat="server" ControlToValidate="myJoinDatePicker">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>    

<asp:RangeValidator ID="rngvJoinDate" runat="server" 
    ControlToValidate="myJoinDatePicker" 
    Type="Date" Display="Dynamic" />
```

**C# Code-Behind:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // set your min join date here 
    rngvJoinDate.MinimumValue = DateTime.MinValue.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"); 

    // set your max join date here
    rngvJoinDate.MaximumValue = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
}
```

Please let me know if you are still getting the error.